# Download multiple csvs from a dynamic page with wget? (or something else)

Tags: asp.net, csv, curl, download, wget

I'm trying to download some publicly available city data, but it's provided in a bunch of files split up by date ranges and I don't want to have to click each link as there are a ton of them. It's a dynamic site (I guess using asp or aspx) so there aren't actual file names, just query results. Is there a way to use Wget or cURL?

The [link](http://data.octo.dc.gov/NewCalendar.aspx?where=Citywide&area=&what=CSV&date=Issueddate&from=6%2F12%2F2000%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM&to=7%2F12%2F2015%2011%3A59%3A00%20PM&dataset=DCRA_PERMIT&datasetid=5&whereInd=0&areaInd=0&whatInd=0&dateInd=0&whenInd=4&disposition=attachment&showextra=1) is this, then click "split the data results into multiple files"

and the links to the files are like `http://data.octo.dc.gov/Attachment.aspx?where=Citywide&area=&what=CSV&date=Issueddate&from=3/1/2001%2011:00:00%20AM&to=4/24/2003%2012:00:00%20AM&dataset=DCRA_PERMIT&datasetid=5&whereInd=0&areaInd=0&whatInd=0&dateInd=0&whenInd=4`

but the date and time ranges vary

The actual file names you download once you click the links look like `DCRA_PERMIT__from03_01_2001__to04_24_2003.csv` but I can't figure out what directory they are from (if any.)

I'm a newbie to this and not much of a coder, I'm trying to use Wget or something else. Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Right, that would be helpful! Mac OS X, whatever the most recent one is -- Yosemite?